# C - copy the last characters from an unknown length string

Tags: c, string

In C programming, suppose that I have some input strings with unknown length like:

`abcde.xxx
abc.xxx
abcdefgh.xxx
....`

How can I take the last 4 characters from them? I tried this way but it doesn't work:

```
char dest[] = "abcdef.ghi";
char s[5];
memset(s, '\n', sizeof s);
strncpy(s, dest - 5, 4);
```

But I can't use `strstr()` since the `dest` may be wrong with the format `xxxx.xxx` like `abcd.xxxy`

Comment: `memcpy(s, strrchr(dest, '.'), 5);`

Comment: [strlen](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strlen.htm) gives you the length of string. Then `strncpy(s, &dest[len-4], 4);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, will crash in case the string doesn't hase a '.' but the idea is the right direction.

Comment: @Devolus _always 3 characters after the dot_

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, the poster says that there can also be malformed strings.

Comment: @Devolus  ┐('～`;)┌

Comment: In your example code, computing `dest - 5` produces undefined behavior, because the result nominally points to a position five `char`s before the *beginning* of `dest`.  Even if the behavior were defined, that would not produce the result you want.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there's no such thing as a "string of unknown length" in C.  If you have a well-formed string, you can always compute its length by calling `strlen`, or search for characters within it by calling `strchr` or `strrchr`, etc.  Are you worried that your strings might not have a `.`, or might have other than 3 characters after the `.`, or that they might be truly malformed, invalid strings which don't have their terminating `\0` at all?  If you just want to remove extensions, I would use `char *p = strrchr(dest, '.'); if(p != NULL) *p = '\0';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char s[5] = {0};
size_t len = 0;
char dest[] = "abcdef.ghi";
char *p = strchr(dest, '.');

if(!p)
{
   // error no '.'
   return;
}

len = strlen(p);
if(len != sizeof(s)-1)
{
    // More or less than 3 characters plus '.'
    return;
}

strcpy(s, p);
```

Answer (score 1):

When the string is null-terminated you can use strlen to get the lenght of the string:

```
char s[5];
size_t len, offset;
char dest[] = "abcdef.ghi";

len = strlen(dest);
memset( s, '\0', sizeof(char)*5);
offset = len-4;
strncpy( s, &dest[offset], 4 );
```

If this is not the case you can loop over the string as an array and look for your dot.

Afterwards you can use this index to calculate your correct offset. But be careful for that solution. If one string does not hate a dt and last free character you can cause an access violation.

Comment: `offset = len-4-1;` --> `offset = len-4;`  strlen does not count null terminator.

Comment: Right, I have fixed it.